# Number of $m$-subsets $Y$ satisfying $|A\cap Y|\le t$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $X$ be a finite set with $n$ elements and $A$ be a subset of $X$ with $a$ elements. Let $m,t\le n$.  I'm interested in counting the number of subsets $Y$ of $X$ with $|Y|=m$ satisfying $|A\cap Y|\le t$.

It seems to be $\sum_{k=0}^t \binom{a}{k}\binom{n-a}{m-k}$ because number of $Y$s satisfying $|A\cap Y|= k$ is the number of $k$-subsets of $A$ times the number of arbitrary selection of the rest elements of $Y$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yep, this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki answer to allow the question to be marked as answered:

As Stefan pointed out in a comment, this is correct.